# space between the border and the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to put a border fitting a image but with some little space between the border and the image.

I'm using this example  http://jsfiddle.net/macwadu/sEz3N/2/

Can anyone help me?

Tanks

Comment: Are you dynamically setting this? If not you won't need to use JS for it, just CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/sEz3N/7/
You can actually put the border around the actual image... why make a wrapper that covers the border part? This way you only need to add a bit of padding and you're done.

Comment: even better that's perfect :D

Comment: That works, but the image has sharp corners, which looks weird when the frame has rounded corners.

Answer (score 2):

removed margin and added 20px (from your moz-border-radius)

http://jsfiddle.net/sEz3N/3/

Comment: tanks all for your fast help i didn't know how to do this `theWidth += 20;`. I was doing the plus the wrong way.  :D

Answer (score 2):

Remove the inline styling of the image. And do the css like this:

```
.imagePanel {   

  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding: 1px;  
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.imagePanel img {
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sEz3N/5/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be good, when I remove the margin from the image

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    theWidth = $(".imagePanel img").width();
    $(".imagePanel").css('width',theWidth+(theWidth*.01));
    $(".imagePanel").css('padding',theWidth*.01);
});
```